# Java swing - fill size

Tags: java, swing

Is there a way to set, when specifying height and width of a component in Swing, that a given object should fill the available vertical/horizontal space? I.e. I would like to say `setSize(*, 100)` to allow horizontal fill.

Comment: try to get the parent width with this.getParent().getWidth() or getHeight() respectively. However, this might not work if you call pack(). So may be consider adding some code and showing us what you do

Comment: Is there a reason you are using `setSize()` and not `setPreferredSize()` with a LayoutManager?

Comment: I do not know what the correct approach is. How would you do that with a layout manager?

Comment: [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) gives you this freedom, to specify, which component can occupy how much space and in which direction. Please have a look at the link provided for more information :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `setSize` with whatever you want, but in the end it is the `LayoutManager` of the parent `Container` which decides what position and what size each component gets.

So by using the correct `LayoutManager` you can typically succeed in letting a component take all the available width.
As you can see in the `BorderLayout` part of the [Visual guide to LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#border) tutorial the `PAGE_START` and `PAGE_END` take all the available width.

By specifying the height as preferred size you will obtain the desired result

Answer (score 0):

A [BorderLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) is probably what you'll want to use, it allows you to set components to North, West, South, East and center.

So for horizontal fill use NORTH, for vertical fill use WEST and for both CENTER.

Comment: OK, but how do I set the height of the button, when I set it to South, without specifying the width?

Comment: @Bober02 when dealing with layout managers, you can only provide "hints".  In this example, you'd provide the preferred size of the button that you wanted (without caring about width to much).  The BorderLayout will then make the button fill the horizontal width of the container.